# read failed: EBADF (Bad file number)

Tags: android

When I try do a copy one file of the external storage for into folder database, this error happens:

> java.io.IOException: read failed: EBADF (Bad file number)

This error happens on the line of while of this method

```
private void copiarBaseDados(InputStream input) throws IOException{
  OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(ConfiguracoesBaseDados.BANCO_PATH + ConfiguracoesBaseDados.BANCO_NOME);
  int tamanho;
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  while ((tamanho = input.read(buffer)) > 0) 
       output.write(buffer, 0, tamanho);
  output.flush();
  output.close();
  input.close();
}
```

Any idea what could be the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check whether your input(stream) exists before reading.

Also see if you have these permissons:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: However to make the copy did not need permission to read and write. Thanks

Comment: Just WRITE_EXTENAL_STORAGE is sufficient. "Any app that declares the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is implicitly granted READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission."

Comment: Define 'exists before reading'. @Rodolfo If your problem was different from this answer why did you mark it as correct?