# EBADF (Bad file number) on inputstream I/O

Tags: android, io, fileinputstream

I have this error

> java.io.IOException: read failed: EBADF (Bad file number)

on this line of code:

```
 while ((input = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
```

What do you think would cause this EBADF bad file number error on this line? Any ideas on how to fix it. I just wanted a working stream to read in the PDF file from the SD and read put back on the SD card again with a different name.

Stack trace

```
07-15 18:47:38.952: W/System.err(2220): java.io.IOException: read failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
07-15 18:47:38.962: W/System.err(2220): at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:432)
07-15 18:47:38.962: W/System.err(2220): at Java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:179)
07-15 18:47:38.962: W/System.err(2220):     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
07-15 18:47:38.962: W/System.err(2220):     at com.example.fileionottext.MainActivity.pdfInAndOut(MainActivity.java:95)
07-15 18:47:38.962: W/System.err(2220):     at com.example.fileionottext.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:47)
07-15 18:47:38.962: W/System.err(2220):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3531)
07-15 18:47:38.962: W/System.err(2220):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14224)
07-15 18:47:38.962: W/System.err(2220):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-15 18:47:38.962: W/System.err(2220):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-15 18:47:38.962: W/System.err(2220):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-15 18:47:38.962: W/System.err(2220):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4699)
07-15 18:47:38.962: W/System.err(2220):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 18:47:38.962: W/System.err(2220):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-15 18:47:38.962: W/System.err(2220):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
```

The rest of the code

```
        public void pdfInAndOut() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
        {
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                File file2;

                file2 = new File("/mnt/sdcard/replacementPdf.pdf");

                // String fileName = "testerPDFCopy.pdf";
                try {
                    if (!file2.exists()) {
                        file2.createNewFile();
                    }
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(file2);
                }
                catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                FileInputStream fis = null;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[888192];

                File fileIn;
                fileIn = new File("/mnt/sdcard/tempPdf.pdf");

                fis = new FileInputStream(fileIn);

                int input = 0;

                while ((input = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) { // <<-- STACK TRACE ERROR
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, input);
                    Log.i("<<<<<>>>>", "fos2 is is; " + buffer[7]);
                    try {
                        fos.flush();
                        fos.close();
                        fis.close();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            textViewOne.setText(String.valueOf(input));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584755/read-failed-ebadf-bad-file-number

Comment: You already posted more or less the same question a couple of days ago - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525255/read-failed-ebadf-bad-file-number-android-read-file-from-sd-card

Comment: i made changes to the code and it still did not work so i wanted to see if i could get any new feedback on this code sample, i thought that was over one week ago

Comment: **NEVER** use hardcoded filepaths. You must use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead.

Comment: `flush()` before `close()` is redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while ((input = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) { // <<-- STACK TRACE ERROR
    fos.write(buffer, 0, input);
```

Either must be a `}`, right? Or the `fis.close` will be executed, and an error will occur.

```
Log.i("<<<<<>>>>", "fos2 is is; " + buffer[7]);

try {
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    fis.close();
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: yes there is the last part of the code is missing. the last few lines i will add it to the code sample now

Comment: I know  the last part of the code is missing.What i mean is the "}"after  " fos.write(buffer, 0, input);" if there isn't,the while sentence will contains the code fis.close(),if the stream is closed,EBADF is about to occur.

Comment: yes!!!!!!!  it works now. no more error!!!!   i am able to write a pdf binary file to the SD card and read it back.   i did not think the error was such a simple mistake that i OVERLOOKED.

Comment: yeah,just a simple mistake.:)

Comment: and @Kevik , a reminder that using ***proper indentation*** is more than just cosmetics ...