# Android parsing xml and AsyncTask doInBackground method never finish

Tags: android, xml, parsing, android-asynctask, bluetooth

I'm new at Android development and I build simple app that receives `xml` file via bluetooth from my computer. Now I want to parse that `xml` file and I want to do that in `AsyncTask` `doInBackground` method. So first of all here I **write bytes to xml file**

```
private void writeBytesToOutputStream(byte[] bytes, String path) {

        File file = new File(path);
        OutputStream out;
        try {
            if(file.exists()){
                file.delete();
            }
            file.createNewFile();

            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            out.write(bytes);
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // method that sets file and later calls execute().
        xml.setFile(file);
    }
```

And here's my inner AsyncTask class.

```
public class XmlParser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject;
        private XmlPullParser myParser;
        private File file;

        String value;

        public XmlParser() {
            try {
                xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                myParser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();

            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void setFile(File file1) {
            file = file1;
            execute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            try {
                if(file == null){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "NOT NULL " + file.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                    myParser.setInput(fis, null);
                    fis.close();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            int event;
            try {
                event = myParser.getEventType();

                while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    String name = myParser.getName();
                    switch (event) {
                        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

                            break;

                        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

                            if (name.equals("from")) {
                                value = myParser.getAttributeValue(null, "value");
                                System.out.println("JUST FOR TEST " + value);
                                event = XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT;
                            }
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    try {
                        event = myParser.next();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            System.out.println("myEND " + aVoid);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "THE END!!! " + aVoid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Somehow method `doInBackground()` never finish. I spend almost four hours trying to fix it but I can't find what's wrong. Also I add my full code

```
public class UiFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 3;

    private String deviceName = null;

    private BluetoothAdapter adapter = null;

    //private ListView listViewConversation;
    //private ArrayAdapter<String> conversationAdapter;

    private Button onButton, offButton;

    private BluetoothConnection connection = null;

    ImageView im;

    private XmlParser xml;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ui, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //listViewConversation = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.in);
        onButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.onButton);
        offButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.offButton);

        im = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        xml = new XmlParser();

        // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
        if (adapter == null) {
            FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            activity.finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
        // setupChat() will then be called during onActivityResult
        if (!adapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            // Otherwise, setup the chat session
        } else if (connection == null) {
            setupChat();
        }
    }

    private void setupChat() {
        //conversationAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.message);

        //listViewConversation.setAdapter(conversationAdapter);

        onButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendCommand(1);
            }
        });

        offButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendCommand(0);
            }
        });

        // Initialize the BluetoothChatService to perform bluetooth connections
        connection = new BluetoothConnection(handler);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE:
                // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    connectDevice(data);
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
                // When the request to enable Bluetooth returns
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // Bluetooth is now enabled, so set up a chat session
                    setupChat();
                } else {
                    // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occurred
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bluetooth not enable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
        }
    }

    private void connectDevice(Intent data) {
        // Get the device MAC address
        String address = data.getExtras().getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
        // Get the BluetoothDevice object
        BluetoothDevice device = adapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        // Attempt to connect to the device
        connection.connect(device);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.secure_connect_scan: {
                // Launch the DeviceListActivity to see devices and do scan
                Intent serverIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DeviceListActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_device_list, menu);
    }

    private void setStatus(CharSequence subTitle) {
        FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
        if (null == activity) {
            return;
        }
        final ActionBar actionBar = activity.getActionBar();
        if (null == actionBar) {
            return;
        }
        actionBar.setSubtitle(subTitle);
    }

    private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
            switch (msg.what) {
                case Constants.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                    switch (msg.arg1) {
                        case BluetoothConnection.STATE_CONNECTED:
                            String name = getString(R.string.title_connected_to, deviceName);
                            setStatus(name);
                            break;
                        case BluetoothConnection.STATE_CONNECTING:
                            setStatus("Connecting...");
                            break;
                        case BluetoothConnection.STATE_NONE:
                            setStatus("Not connected");
                            break;
                        case BluetoothConnection.STATE_LISTEN:
                    }
                    break;
                case Constants.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                    deviceName = msg.getData().getString(Constants.DEVICE_NAME);
                    if (activity != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Connected to " + deviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
                case Constants.MESSAGE_TOAST:
                    if (null != activity) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, msg.getData().getString(Constants.TOAST), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
                case Constants.MESSAGE_READ:
                    byte[] readBuffer = (byte[]) msg.obj;

                    //Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(readBuffer, 0, msg.arg1);
                    //im.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                    String path = activity.getFilesDir() + "/mano.xml";

                    writeBytesToOutputStream(readBuffer, path);

                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    private void sendCommand(int command) {
        if (connection.getState() != BluetoothConnection.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You are not connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(command).array();
        connection.write(bytes);
    }

    private void writeBytesToOutputStream(byte[] bytes, String path) {

        File file = new File(path);
        OutputStream out;
        try {
            if(file.exists()){
                file.delete();
            }
            file.createNewFile();

            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            out.write(bytes);
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        xml.setFile(file);
    }

    public class XmlParser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject;
        private XmlPullParser myParser;
        private File file;

        String value;

        public XmlParser() {
            try {
                xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                myParser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();

            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void setFile(File file1) {
            file = file1;
            execute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            try {
                if(file == null){ // failas == null
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "NOT NULL " + file.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                    myParser.setInput(fis, null);
                    fis.close();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            int event;
            try {
                event = myParser.getEventType();

                while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    String name = myParser.getName();
                    switch (event) {
                        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

                            break;

                        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

                            if (name.equals("from")) {
                                value = myParser.getAttributeValue(null, "value");
                                System.out.println("JUST FOR TEST " + value);
                                event = XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT;
                            }
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    try {
                        event = myParser.next();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            System.out.println("myEND " + aVoid);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "THE END!!! " + aVoid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

my document

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Comment: have you tried debugging through the whole parsing? maybe he gets stuck in a try-catch and does not do the xpp.next()

Comment: try to log/debug the exception on `try {
                        event = myParser.next();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }`

Comment: Is the xml you post on your edit the sent xml or the receive one (mano.xml saved using the `writeBytesToOutputStream` method) ? Maybe the received file is corrupted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fount the solution. I need to close `FileInputStream` on `onPostExecute` not on `onPreExecute` method.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess but this may be your problem

```
       try {
            event = myParser.next();
       } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

This is because if for some reason your parser cannot move to the next element - maybe your xml isn't properly formatted? - then this error would never escalate, thereby leaving you stuck in an infinite loop.

What you could do instead is call "break". if an exception is thrown. Also, use the Log class for logging, like this:

```
       try {
            event = myParser.next();
       } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage();
            break;
       }
```

Comment: Or just don't catch the exception there but on the upper level (where the XmlPullParserException is caugh) = prettier code :3

Comment: Hm I got this `read failed: EBADF (Bad file number)` I also Edit  my question and add document that I send. What is wrong with my xml?

Comment: For EBADF check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584755/read-failed-ebadf-bad-file-number

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
while (myParser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        //code       
}
```